# Bootstrap 3 Alert - Show with jQuery or JS

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap 3 alert div like it

```
        <div class="alert" style="background-color:#9FF781;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Done</strong> Deleted Successfully.
        </div>
```

And I am getting output like this-

[image]

But the problem is it is visible from the time of page loading and when I click on the close button, it disappears.

I like it will disappears at first and will come to front with a JS call.

So, how can I make it visible from the first.

And how can I restore it with JS or jQuery.

Is there any way?

Please help.

Comment: You could set it hidden with styles and then use jQuery to `.show()` the element again. Start by changing the `style` to `background-color:#9FF781; display:none;`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap Alert [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)

You have to use `hide` or `show` (jQuery Methods) to hide or show alert `div`.

Check this

```js
$('#toggleAlert').click(function() {
  $('.alert').toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" style='display:none;'>Test
  <button data-dismiss="alert" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<input type="button" id="toggleAlert" value="Toggle Alert" />
```

Note: The close button in the alert, If  you click on that, the Bootstrap removes the `alert` div from DOM. So if you want to show the `alert` again, then use a button to `toggle` the div without using close button in alert.